# Failing to load a library in R

Tags: r, r-library

I have just installed the package LiftOver from Bioconductor (https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/html/liftOver.html) however when I try to load the library I get the following error

```
> library(liftOver)

Loading required package: gwascat

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gwascat’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required
Error: package ‘gwascat’ could not be loaded
```

Do I need to update my R/R studio?

Answer (score 1):

Try `install.packages("cli")` or reinstall *cli* completely (`remove.packages("cli")` before installation)